# Python - not able to extract value of hidden input

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup, hidden-field

I am trying to extract the value of a hidden input tag.
Even though the element exists in the HTML i can't find it with bs4.

This is the error message i get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This is the html on the webpage:

```
<form id="exampleid" class="exampleclass" action="/ex/ex-ex/ex/2" method="post">
    
    <more html>
                                
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
    </div></form>
```

And this is my current code:

```
csrf = soup.find("form", {"id": "exampleid"})
csrf = csrf.find('input', {'name': 'csrf'}).get("value")
print(csrf)
```

I would appreciate any kind of help as it is really bothering me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ```print(soup)``` and check if it has what you are looking for ? It would be better if you post the URL for us to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection is still working, think there is another issue, maybe you wont get the html you expect.

As alternativ to select and get the value of this hidden `<input>` you can use the following `css selector`:

```
soup.select_one('#exampleid input[name*="csrf"]')['value']
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<form id="exampleid" class="exampleclass" action="/ex/ex-ex/ex/2" method="post">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
</div></form>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

csrf = soup.select_one('#exampleid input[name*="csrf"]')['value']

print(csrf)
```

#### Output

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```